# Parsing html content and showing in html

Tags: angularjs

In my controller:

```
$scope.currencySymbol = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#8377;');
```

In html page:

```
{{currencySymbol}}
```

It's showing `&#8377;` in the page, but I want it to show the ₹ symbol.

Comment: look at ASCI codes if is this, and the doc of trustAsHtml

Comment: I want to use rupees symbol following this https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/ to get currency symbol

Comment: use "&#8377;" directy without trustAsHtml, and tell us

Comment: I am getting different symbol values according to different currency

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display rupee sign with any number then you can do with below mentioned code.

```
{{1 | currency:"INR": true}}
```

This will print

```
₹1.00
```

Comment: I tried this `{{1 | currency:currencyCode: true}}` currencyCode is my dynamic value that is showing  INR 1. Insted if INR i want to show symbol

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-bind-html like this

```
<span ng-bind-html="currencySymbol"></span>
```